# How to disable Protected Mode in Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9, group-policy, protected-mode

I need to disable Protected Mode for the Local Intranet in Internet Explorer 9.  So I go into Wrench/Internet Options/Security Tab/click on Local Intranet.

The `Enable Protected Mode` checkbox is grayed out and is checked.  On the bottom it states that `some settings are managed by your system administrator.`

[image]

Yes, I am logged into the a domain account, however, I am an admin on my machine and I've tried starting IE as an Administrator.  What's more puzzling, is that I logged in as a local user and the checkbox is still disabled and it states that some settings are managed by a sys admin.

I've tried looking around the Group Policy, but couldn't find anything that worked (though this is the first time I used the GP Editor).

How can I disable the Protected Mode for the Local Intranet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look in group policy, its under user configuration /or computer configuration --> Administrative template --> WIndows components --> Internet Explorer --> Internet Control panel --> Security page

There just go to zone that you want to set.

[image: screen shot]

Or you can run GP report to see what setting is applied. To do that, open up cmd then type in

```
gpresult /h gpresult.html
```

you report will be save in your current directory when you start cmd. Once you have the report, look at the bottom of the page, you will see settings that have been applied.

Here is mine, I've just enable one GP just to test it

[image: gpresult]

Comment: I tried that - no dice.  Nothing changed.

Comment: so it didn't work but it still is the accepted answer?

Comment: Remember that you have to Enable the GPO "Turn on Protected Mode" first and then disable the option "Protected Mode" within that GPO. 

Don't just set the "Turn on Protected Mode" GPO to Disable, because that will not work.

Answer (score -1):

From mwhat I have read it is a reg change.

SO reg change required to turn it off from popping up is as follows.

HKCU - Software - Microsoft - Internet Explorer - Main
New DWORD
NoProtectedModeBanner
Decimal value of 1

Comment: a domain policy would override any manual modification to the registry.

Answer (score -1):

as I understand it local admin does not win over GP pushed as a computer policy on the domain.  The computer gets the policy and that policy overrides the user side.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! I know you are new to this site, but wanted to make you aware you are posting an answer to a 3-year old question that has an accepted answer already. There is nothing wrong with doing so, just realize it may not be responded to or accepted.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score -2):

Another solution is to simply disable IE Enhanced Security Configuration. This resolved the issue for me