# What is the Registry setting to enable protected mode in a specific zone

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-registry

Okay, now to be clear, I am not talking about enabling or disabling protected mode in general across the board for IE. I am talking about doing so on a per  security zone basis using only registry. In other words like just for the Intranet Zone.

So yes, I already know about tab proc growth = 0, but this disables protected mode and puts all of the IE tab processes in the same process.

What I am talking about:

[image]

Essentially I am asking [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/377745/how-to-disable-protected-mode-in-internet-explorer-9), but I would like the answer in the form of a registry key instead of a group policy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I inspected the ADMX files (Group Policy setting definitions) to figure out the structure of these data; the relevant settings are in `inetres.admx` in `\Windows\PolicyDefinitions`.

These settings are stored in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones`. Under `Zones` is a subkey for each zone, named numerically:

- `0` is the Local Machine zone
- `1` is the Intranet zone
- `2` is the Trusted Sites zone
- `3` is the Internet zone
- `4` is the Restricted Sites zone

(There can also be a `Lockdown_Zones` subkey under `Internet Settings` that applies - you guessed it - to the locked down version of the corresponding zone.)

Under each numerically-named key, you can create or set a `REG_DWORD` value named `2500` to contol whether Protected Mode is enabled for the zone. Setting that value to `0` enables Protected Mode; a setting of `3` disables it.

So, to enable Protected Mode for the Internet zone, set this entry to `0`:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3\2500
```

---

*If you want to read/write the policy version of these settings:* The Group Policy settings shown in the question and answer you linked are, like the vast majority of Group Policy options, implemented as Registry entries. Policy entries are stored in `HKCU\Software\Policies` (for a single user) or `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies` (for the machine). Under `Policies`, `Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones` is exactly as described earlier, but will not allow the user to change the settings. Per-user policy cannot be modified by programs running as that user, unless the user is an administrator.

Answer (score 1):

To enable protected mode (tick the box as you requested) set the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main` key  to `"Isolation"="PMEM"`.